# web service vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services

```
   Dim j As New SqlDataSource
   Dim xId As String
   Dim y = j.ConnectionString("Data Source=pcname;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True")
   Dim query As String
   query = "SELECT *  FROM x WHERE username =" + Username + " AND Password = " + Password
   Dim result = j.SelectCommand(query)
   xId = j.SelectParameters('xId')
   return xId
```

I do no it is right way to return XId field.

A bit confuse since this is first time i touch vb since vb6. Lot of changes.

Software Use : Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.
Database Use : Sql Server  2008 Express.

Comment: You need to tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i just want to output the xId field

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a starting point of how to use SqlConnection

- [SQL In VB.NET](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216920.html#)
- [SqlCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

You should also seriously avoid using string concatenation for the Sql Query to avoid [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Rather use [SqlParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)